# Calling each article tag separately from within another loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have an article, and each article has tags. Right now I call all the tags together:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <div class="articlebox">
    <article>
      <h4>
        <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>
      </h4>
        <%= markdown article.body %>
      <span class="articletagbox">  
        <%= article.tag_tokens %>
      </span>   
<% end %>
```

Right now my class goes around all the article tags. I want it to go around each article tag individually.

I've tried a simple

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
```

but that gives me an undefined method "each" nilclass error.

I know this is pretty simple, but I just can't figure out what I'm supposed to change to make it work. I assume I need to define something in my article model?

Thanks!

EDIT

So right now my code looks like this:

```
<% article.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <span class="articletagbox">  
    <%= article.tag_tokens %>
  </span>   
<% end %>
```

and the method in article.rb is:

```
def tag_tokens
  self.tags.collect{|t| t.name}.join(", ")
end
```

which is returning all the tags associated with each article the same number of times as there are tags.

So for example, if I have three tags on an article: tag1, tag2, tag3 I get

```
<class>tag1 tag2 tag3</class> <class>tag1 tag2 tag3</class> <class>tag1 tag2 tag3</class>
```

Instead I want

```
<class>tag1</class> <class>tag2</class> <class>tag3</class>
```

So I'm just not sure why I'm getting all the tags associated with each article returned together, but the same number of times as there are tags. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one article `has many :tags` then in the article loop do

```
<% article.tags.each do |tag| %>
```

Following your edit : you're outputting a method called on the article while looping on tags. Doesn't make sense, you're looping on tags, call `tag.name` instead!

Check slhck answer for the specific syntax

Comment: That partially worked! I have three tags that show up three times wrapped in my class as a group.

Comment: Do I need to write a method to call each tag individually? If so, what would it look like? Thanks!

Comment: @Arel What do you mean by "calling each tag individually"? The `.each` method calls the block for every tag in the article individually already. Or do you want to get *all* tags ever created, not related to any article, and iterate over them?

Comment: @Arel Please edit your question and clarify it rather than in comments, thank you!

Comment: So right now my code looks like this:

<% article.tags.each do |tag| %>
   <span class="articletagbox"> 
     <%= article.tag_tokens %>
   </span> 
 <% end %>     

and the method is:
def tag_tokens
    self.tags.collect{|t| t.name}.join(", ")
  end

which is returning all the tags associated with each article the same number of times as there are tags. So for example, if I have three tags on an article: tag1 tag2 tag3 I get <class>tag1 tag2 tag3</class><class>tag1 tag2 tag3</class><class>tag1 tag2 tag3</class>

Instead I want <class>tag1</class><class>tag2</class><class>tag3</class>

Comment: I moved the above comment up to the original post to make it easier to read.

Comment: AWESOME!!! THANKS!! That was a huge help! Thanks guys! I'm just starting to get a grasp of how to do all this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You said you wanted:

```
<class>tag1</class> <class>tag2</class> <class>tag3</class>
```

I'm assuming by `class` you mean the `span` formatting that should be applied to each tag individually? Just get rid of the `tag_tokens` method. It would probably be bad style to define formatting methods in your tag's model anyway – rather do the formatting in a view, or a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

In your view, inside the loop where you go over all articles, just do:

```
<% article.tags.each do |tag| %>
  <span class="articletagbox"><%= tag.name %></span>
<% end %>
```

This would output:

```
<span class="articletagbox">tag1</span>
<span class="articletagbox">tag2</span>
```

... and so on.